# Change y-axis in Dygraph to NOT be scientific notation

Tags: r, axis-labels, dygraphs

I have created a dygraph and want change the y-axis from scientific notation to decimal form.

This is what the code looks like:

```
df_xts <- xts(df$Var1,order.by=df$Date)
dygraph(A_xts, 
        main="DF - Var1",group="group1") %>%
  dySeries("V1",label="Var1") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = FALSE,colors=c("blue")) %>%
  dyRangeSelector()
```

I'm guessing it would be placed under dyOptions but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: I already tried that, thanks though @RHertel

Comment: See http://dygraphs.com/options.html#maxNumberWidth (dygraphs will switch to scientific notation for large numbers)

Comment: Thanks, I saw this page but I'm not sure how you would plug max number width into the code. Could you please display an answer related to example I posted? @bergant

Comment: Of course. Do you have some sample data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With my sample data it looks like this:

```
df_xts <- xts(runif(10) * 1e10, order.by = as.POSIXct(x = 1:10, origin = "2015-01-01") )

dygraph(df_xts, main="DF - Var1") %>%
  dySeries("V1",label="Var1") %>%
  dyOptions(maxNumberWidth = 20, stackedGraph = FALSE,colors=c("blue")) %>%
  dyRangeSelector
```

Comment: This was reallyhelpful, I now understand how to use those functions on that page. Opportunities opened! Thanks @bergant